# PHP add Months fails

Tags: php, time

i'm using

`$membercontract_enddate = date('d.m.Y', strtotime("+'$months_o_duration' months", strtotime('$membercontract_startdate')));`

`$membercontract_startdate` contains a timestamp for 9-Apr-2014

`$months_o_duration` contains the number of months, in my example 10,

`$membercontract_enddate` should be startdate plus months, in this cas 9-Feb-2015

But, actually, it always gets 01.01.1970. Why is that?

Comment: Probably because of the unnecessary quotes in your `strtotime()` argument. It should be `$membercontract_enddate = date('d.m.Y', strtotime("+$months_o_duration months", strtotime($membercontract_startdate)));`. Notice how I changed the quotes.

Comment: your solution gets RED in Dreamweaver. But i will try on Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing how you're actually declaring the rest of your variables, it looks to be most likely caused by your use of single quotes (`'`) around your `$membercontract_startdate` reference - in PHP, variables in single quotes aren't interpreted.

For more information, the [PHP Manual Strings page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) has information about the differences between single and double quotes.

Comment: why do singele quotes get interpreted in PHP Querys? ... ` "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = '$var'" ` ?

Comment: @HKK Because they're already encapsulated in double quotes, so because the string itself is declared using double quotes, variable names are automatically expanded anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` will convert string to unix epoch. so the final result should be a string.

```
$membercontract_startdate = "09-Apr-2014";
$months_o_duration = 10;

$unix_start = strtotime($membercontract_startdate);
$months_o_duration_seconds = $months_o_duration * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60;
$unix_end = $unix_start + $months_o_duration_seconds;

$membercontract_enddate = date('d.m.Y', $unix_end);
echo $membercontract_enddate;

// out = 03.02.2015 // because of 30 days 

// in order to get 9-Feb-2015
$membercontract_startdate = "09-Apr-2014";
$unix_start = strtotime($membercontract_startdate, "+10 month");
$membercontract_enddate = date('d.m.Y', $unix_start);
echo $membercontract_enddate;

// out = 09.04.2014
```

You can do it in one line .. I am just explaining